# Selecting Multiple Tables in MySQL Stops me from using the <= expression

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using a `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT knowledge.*, 
       sortflagitems.* 
FROM   knowledge, 
       sortflagitems 
WHERE  sortflagitems.flagid = :FlagID 
       AND knowledge.id = sortflagitems.kid 
       AND sortflagitems.cid = :CID 
       AND knowledge.archived = :Nothing 
       AND sortflagitems.flagdate <= :Now 
ORDER  BY sortflagitems.sortorder
```

That produces this error:

```
 Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

However if I change the `SELECT` Query To this:

```
SELECT knowledge.*, 
       sortflagitems.* 
FROM   knowledge, 
       sortflagitems 
WHERE  sortflagitems.flagid = :FlagID 
       AND knowledge.id = sortflagitems.kid 
       AND sortflagitems.cid = :CID 
       AND knowledge.archived = :Nothing 
       AND sortflagitems.flagdate = :Now 
ORDER  BY sortflagitems.sortorder
```

That doesn't product any errors

Notice that this line `SortFlagItems.FlagDate=:Now` was changed from `SortFlagItems.FlagDate<=:Now`

My only theory is that for some reason when you Select Multiple Tables you can't use the `<=` operator (note that using the `<` operator produces the same error)? I can't think of anything else..

---

Here is the full PHP Code:

```
$DBParams = array('FlagID'=>$_GET['flag'], 'CID'=>$row['CatID'], 'Nothing'=>0, 'Now'=>strtotime('now'));
$results = $Db->rquery('
                    SELECT Knowledge.*, SortFlagItems.*
            FROM Knowledge, SortFlagItems
            WHERE SortFlagItems.FlagID=:FlagID
            AND Knowledge.id = SortFlagItems.KID
            AND SortFlagItems.CID=:CID
            AND Knowledge.Archived=:Nothing
            AND SortFlagItems.FlagDate<=:Now
            ORDER BY SortFlagItems.SortOrder', $DBParams);
```

Here is the `rquery` function:

```
function rquery($query, $params = NULL) {
    $this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();
    $stmt->execute($params);

    $results = $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);

    return $results;
}
```

And the constructor:

```
public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db) {
    $this->_mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    $this->_mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

Comment: Please, stop using implicit join syntax.

Comment: I think this is a php problem, try to show the php part please. You did not bind all your parameters

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting an error but you could try changing ':Now' to 'now()' if you would like to use the current date/time.

Comment: Just added in the full PHP Code

Comment: what does rquery do? is it a wrapper for bind params? The problem is most probably there

Comment: Just added in the rquery function and the class constructor

Comment: filter_var is 'sanitizing' the '<' - treating it like an open tag. So the rest of the query (with the bound param) is removed.

Comment: @etherbunny Well spotted.

Comment: What is the best way to get around that problem? That makes sense

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I have no idea what you mean by this: `Please, stop using implicit join syntax`

Comment: @Talon Explicit `JOIN` syntax is ANSI-92 standard

Comment: @Talon - as you are using prepared statements I think you are ok skipping the 'sanitize' step. YMMV but from what I've read I believe you're ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution will be to remove filter_var from your method:

```
function rquery($query, $params = NULL) {
    $this->_query = $query;
    $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();
    $stmt->execute($params);

    $results = $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);

    return $results;
}
```

The binding will be preventing sql injection for you.
You can use `filter_var()` on your parameters inside `_dynamicBindResults` if you have to.

Or you can use it on each parameter before passing your query:

```
$DBParams = array('FlagID'=>filter_var($_GET['flag'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),...);
```

And for the join here is an explicit join:

```
SELECT Knowledge.*, SortFlagItems.*
FROM Knowledge
INNER JOIN SortFlagItems ON Knowledge.id = SortFlagItems.KID
WHERE SortFlagItems.FlagID=:FlagID
AND SortFlagItems.CID=:CID
AND Knowledge.Archived=:Nothing
AND SortFlagItems.FlagDate<=:Now
ORDER BY SortFlagItems.SortOrder
```